# How to add Chapter before Chapter Number

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

I'm trying to format my thesis, but I don't fully understand everything in the style file.
I need "Chapter" to go before the chapter number in the ToC, followed by the chapter name etc.

I've tried the suggested fixes for similar situations, but they don't work with the style file I'm using (probably it's just out of date) - and I don't know it well enough to figure out a workaround.

Thanks for any help!

"minimum" working example:
.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn]{lsuetd}
\usepackage{setspace,graphicx,dsfont,verbatim,paralist,indentfirst}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{pdfpages,amssymb}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
    escapechar         = ",
    mlshowsectionrules = true
    %   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    %   columns=fullflexible
    %   frame=single
}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\newcommand\blankfootnote[1]{%
    \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{#1}%
    \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
}
\allowdisplaybreaks
%\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
%fix margins
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.50in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.50in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.00in}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.75em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}

%\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.75cm}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}}
\usepackage{epstopdf}% To incorporate .eps illustrations using PDFLaTeX, etc.
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
%\titleformat{\section}
%{\singlespacing}
%{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}
%{1em}
%{\spacedlowsmallcaps}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}% Support for small, `sub' figures and tables
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
%\usepackage{subcaption} % for two figures in 1

\usepackage{booktabs}% for booktables
\usepackage{cite} % for citations
\usepackage{soul} % for highliting
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{inconsolata} % typewriter font
\newcommand{\printtblhdra}{%
    \hfill
    \begingroup
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \begin{tabularx}{0.41\textwidth}{ @{} l *{3}X r @{} }
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries\shortstack[l]{Not Confident}}
        &&
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries\shortstack[r]{Very Confident}}
        
    \end{tabularx}
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\printtblhdrb}{%
    \hfill
    \begingroup
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \begin{tabularx}{0.41\textwidth}{ @{} l *{3}X r @{} }
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries\shortstack[l]{Never}}
        &&
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries\shortstack[r]{Always}}
        
    \end{tabularx}
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\printtblhdrc}{%
    \hfill
    \begingroup
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \begin{tabularx}{0.41\textwidth}{ @{} l *{3}X r @{} }
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries\shortstack[l]{Disagree}}
        &&
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries\shortstack[r]{Agree}}
        
    \end{tabularx}
    \endgroup
}


\newcommand{\usetbl}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|*5{P|}@{}}
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand\prop[1]{%
    \item
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{#1}%
    %   \qquad
    %\parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{\usetbl}%
}

% for
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge{16pt}{18}} %Redefined for use in dissertation title
\renewcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge{14pt}{18}} % Redefined for use in chapter titles
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{12pt}{18}} % Redefined for use in section titles
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{12pt}{18}} % Redefined for use in subsection titles
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[hidelinks, bookmarksopen=false,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
    \renewcommand\@tocrmarg{9.55em}
    \renewcommand*\l@chapter{\@dottedtocline{0}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
    \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{3.1em}}
    \let\l@table\l@figure
    %
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    

    \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{12pt}}
    \pagebreak
    \singlespacing
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \tableofcontents
    \pagebreak

    \singlespacing
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
    \setlength{\intextsep}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
    % \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %do not indent paragraphs
    % Chapters are added here
    \chapter{Bayesian Statistics and Mathematical Biology}


\end{document}
```

style file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{lsuetd}
[2004/02/16 v1.4f
Modified LaTeX document class]
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\newif\if@restonecol
\newif\if@titlepage
\@titlepagetrue
\newif\if@openright
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
{\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}}
\DeclareOption{a5paper}
{\setlength\paperheight {210mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {148mm}}
\DeclareOption{b5paper}
{\setlength\paperheight {250mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {176mm}}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}
{\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{legalpaper}
{\setlength\paperheight {14in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{executivepaper}
{\setlength\paperheight {10.5in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {7.25in}}
\DeclareOption{landscape}
{\setlength\@tempdima   {\paperheight}%
    \setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {\@tempdima}}
\fi
\if@compatibility
\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}
\else
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
\fi
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{titlepage}{\@titlepagetrue}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{notitlepage}{\@titlepagefalse}
\fi
\if@compatibility
\else
\DeclareOption{openright}{\@openrighttrue}
\DeclareOption{openany}{\@openrightfalse}
\fi
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
\fi
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}
\DeclareOption{leqno}{\input{leqno.clo}}
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\input{fleqn.clo}}
\DeclareOption{openbib}{%
    \AtEndOfPackage{%
        \renewcommand\@openbib@code{%
            \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
            \itemindent -\bibindent
            \listparindent \itemindent
            \parsep \z@
        }%
        \renewcommand\newblock{\par}}%
}
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany}
\ProcessOptions
\input{size1\@ptsize.clo}
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{}
\setlength\parskip{0\p@ \@plus \p@}
\@lowpenalty   51
\@medpenalty  151
\@highpenalty 301
\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.3}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{3}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.5}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.5}
\if@twoside
\def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
        \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
                \fi
                ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
        \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
                \thesection. \ %
                \fi
                ##1}}}}
\else
\def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
        \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
                \fi
                ##1}}}}
\fi
\def\ps@myheadings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\chaptermark\@gobble
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble
}
\if@titlepage
\newcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
        \let\footnotesize\small
        \let\footnoterule\relax
        \let \footnote \thanks
        \null\vfil
        \vskip 60\p@
        \begin{center}%
            {\LARGE \@title \par}%
            \vskip 3em%
            {\large
                \lineskip .75em%
                \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
                    \@author
                \end{tabular}\par}%
            \vskip 1.5em%
            {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
        \end{center}\par
        \@thanks
        \vfil\null
    \end{titlepage}%
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
    \global\let\thanks\relax
    \global\let\maketitle\relax
    \global\let\@thanks\@empty
    \global\let\@author\@empty
    \global\let\@date\@empty
    \global\let\@title\@empty
    \global\let\title\relax
    \global\let\author\relax
    \global\let\date\relax
    \global\let\and\relax
}
\else
\newcommand\maketitle{\par
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
        \hb@xt@1.8em{%
            \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
    \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
    \@maketitle
    \else
    \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
    \fi
    \else
    \newpage
    \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
    \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
    \endgroup
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
    \global\let\thanks\relax
    \global\let\maketitle\relax
    \global\let\@maketitle\relax
    \global\let\@thanks\@empty
    \global\let\@author\@empty
    \global\let\@date\@empty
    \global\let\@title\@empty
    \global\let\title\relax
    \global\let\author\relax
    \global\let\date\relax
    \global\let\and\relax
}
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em%
    \begin{center}%
        \let \footnote \thanks
        {\LARGE \@title \par}%
        \vskip 1.5em%
        {\large
            \lineskip .5em%
            \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
                \@author
            \end{tabular}\par}%
        \vskip 1em%
        {\large \@date}%
    \end{center}%
    \par
    \vskip 1.5em}
\fi
\newcommand*\chaptermark[1]{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\newcounter {part}
\newcounter {chapter}
\newcounter {section}[chapter]
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
\newcounter {subsubsection}[subsection]
\newcounter {paragraph}[subsubsection]
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]
\renewcommand \thepart {\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand \thechapter {\@arabic\c@chapter}
\renewcommand \thesection {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection.}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection.}
\renewcommand\theparagraph    {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}
\newcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}
\newcommand\part{%
    \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
    \else
    \clearpage
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
    \else
    \@tempswafalse
    \fi
    \null\vfil
    \secdef\@part\@spart}

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}  #1}%
    \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\@chapapp #1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
        \interlinepenalty \@M
        \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
        \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
        \par
        \vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\centering
        \interlinepenalty \@M
        \normalfont
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
    \if@twoside
    \if@openright
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \newpage
    \fi
    \fi
    \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
    \fi}
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{12\p@}}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter} #1}%@chapapp
    %  To add all caps to TOC , uncomment the line below and comment
    %  the line above.
    %          {\uppercase{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}%
    \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    %%              \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{12\p@}}%
    %%                  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{12\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
    \else
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    %%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter.\space
        %% Comment out the following line to put chapter number and title ont the same line.
        %        \par\nobreak
        %%        \vskip 12\p@
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 6\p@
}}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
    \else
    \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
    \@afterheading
    \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    %%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
        %%    \vskip 40\p@
}}
\newcommand\section{\vspace{-0.66em} \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {-0.0002ex \@plus -0ex \@minus -.0ex}%
    {0.01ex \@plus.0ex}%
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {0.0001ex\@plus 0ex \@minus -.0ex}%
    {0.01ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {-0.0001ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {0.01ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\hspace{-2.15em} $\bullet$ \hspace{0.6em} \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
    {0ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\if@twocolumn
\setlength\leftmargini  {2em}
\else
\setlength\leftmargini  {2.5em}
\fi
\leftmargin  \leftmargini
\setlength\leftmarginii  {2.2em}
\setlength\leftmarginiii {1.87em}
\setlength\leftmarginiv  {1.7em}
\if@twocolumn
\setlength\leftmarginv  {.5em}
\setlength\leftmarginvi {.5em}
\else
\setlength\leftmarginv  {1em}
\setlength\leftmarginvi {1em}
\fi
\setlength  \labelsep  {.5em}
\setlength  \labelwidth{\leftmargini}
\addtolength\labelwidth{-\labelsep}
\@beginparpenalty -\@lowpenalty
\@endparpenalty   -\@lowpenalty
\@itempenalty     -\@lowpenalty
\renewcommand\theenumi{\@arabic\c@enumi}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\@alph\c@enumii}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\@roman\c@enumiii}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\@Alph\c@enumiv}
\newcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\newcommand\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\newcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\newcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
\newcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}
\newcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}
\newcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}
\newenvironment{description}
{\list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
{\endlist}
\newcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
    \normalfont\bfseries #1}
\if@titlepage
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \titlepage
    \null\vfil
    \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
    \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
\end{center}}%
{\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \section*{\abstractname}%
    \else
    \small
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
    \fi}
{\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\newenvironment{verse}
{\let\\\@centercr
    \list{}{\itemsep      \z@
        \itemindent   -1.5em%
        \listparindent\itemindent
        \rightmargin  \leftmargin
        \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}%
    \item\relax}
{\endlist}
\newenvironment{quotation}
{\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
        \itemindent    \listparindent
        \rightmargin   \leftmargin
        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
    \item\relax}
{\endlist}
\newenvironment{quote}
{\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
    \item\relax}
{\endlist}
\if@compatibility
\newenvironment{titlepage}
{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
    \@restonecolfalse\newpage
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \setcounter{page}\z@
}%
{\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
}
\else
\newenvironment{titlepage}
{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
    \@restonecolfalse\newpage
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \setcounter{page}\@ne
}%
{\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
    \if@twoside\else
    \setcounter{page}\@ne
    \fi
}
\fi
\newcommand\appendix{\par
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
    \setcounter{section}{0}%
    \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
    \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
\setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
\setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
\setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
\skip\@mpfootins = \skip\footins
\setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
\setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}
\@addtoreset {equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand\theequation
{\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@equation}
\newcounter{figure}[chapter]
\renewcommand \thefigure
{\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\ftype@figure{1}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}
\newenvironment{figure}
{\@float{figure}}
{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{12\p@}} \end@float}
\newenvironment{figure*}
{\@dblfloat{figure}}
{\end@dblfloat}
\newcounter{table}[chapter]
\renewcommand \thetable
{\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@table}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
\def\ftype@table{2}
\def\ext@table{lot}
\def\fnum@table{\tablename\nobreakspace\thetable}
\newenvironment{table}
{\@float{table}}
{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{12\p@}} \end@float}
\newenvironment{table*}
{\@dblfloat{table}}
{\end@dblfloat}
\newlength\abovecaptionskip
\newlength\belowcaptionskip
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10\p@}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0\p@}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip
    \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
    \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
    \fi
    \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{0.55em}
\newcommand\@tocrmarg{10.55em}
\newcommand\@dotsep{1.5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
    \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
            \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\newcommand*\l@part[2]{%
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
    \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
    \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
    {\leavevmode
        \large \bfseries \@chapapp #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
    \nobreak
    \global\@nobreaktrue
    \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
    \fi}
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
    \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
    \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
    \leavevmode \bfseries
    \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
    \hskip -\leftskip
\@chapapp   #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2} \par
    \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
    \fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1.\hfil}}
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
    \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
    \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
    \leavevmode \bfseries
    \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
    \hskip -\leftskip
    #1\nobreak\mdseries
    \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
    \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
    \fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{3.8em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{7.0em}{3.2em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{10.2em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
    \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand\listoftables{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
    \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename}%
    \@mkboth{%
        \MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\let\l@table\l@figure
\newdimen\bibindent
\setlength\bibindent{1.5em}
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
{\chapter*{\bibname}%
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
    \vspace*{10pt}% NEW
    \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
    {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
    \sloppy
    \clubpenalty4000
    \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
    \widowpenalty4000%
    \sfcode`\.\@m}
{\def\@noitemerr
    {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \endlist}
\newcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
\let\@openbib@code\@empty
\newenvironment{theindex}
{\if@twocolumn
    \@restonecolfalse
    \else
    \@restonecoltrue
    \fi
    \twocolumn[\@makeschapterhead{\indexname}]%
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
    {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
    \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
    \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
    \columnseprule \z@
    \columnsep 35\p@
    \let\item\@idxitem}
{\if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi}
\newcommand\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@}
\newcommand\subitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{20\p@}}
\newcommand\subsubitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{30\p@}}
\newcommand\indexspace{\par \vskip 10\p@ \@plus5\p@ \@minus3\p@\relax}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
    \kern-3\p@
    \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
    \kern2.6\p@}
\@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter}
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
\newcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents \vspace{12\p@}}
\newcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures \vspace{12\p@}}
\newcommand\listtablename{List of Tables \vspace{12\p@}}
\newcommand\bibname{References}
\newcommand\indexname{Index}
\newcommand\figurename{Figure}
\newcommand\tablename{Table}
\newcommand\partname{Part}
\newcommand\chaptername{Chapter}
\newcommand\appendixname{Appendix}
\newcommand\abstractname{Abstract}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
    January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
    July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
    \space\number\day, \number\year}
\setlength\columnsep{10\p@}
\setlength\columnseprule{0\p@}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\if@twoside
\else
\raggedbottom
\fi
\if@twocolumn
\twocolumn
\sloppy
\flushbottom
\else
\onecolumn
\fi
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `lsuetd.cls'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to edit your copy of `lsuetd.cls`. Open the file in a text editor and go to the definition of macro `\@chapter` on line 291. A few lines below you find

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
{\protect\numberline{\thechapter} #1}%@chapapp
```

Replace it by

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}
%{\protect\numberline{\thechapter} #1}%@chapapp
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to add a period after 'Chapter #'?

Comment: Use `\@chapapp\ \thechapter. #1` instead of `\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1`. `\@chapapp` expands to Chapter (defined further up in the file), and `\thechapter` to the number. So you can judge yourself where to insert further stuff.

Comment: That worked - is there a way to NOT indent the "chapter 1. etc" line? And now I've noticed two periods after section numbers in ToC (not in MWE - lmk if I should open another Q) - thank you

Comment: Figured it out - edited numberline and tempdima for l@section part of style file

Comment: @rdale Great, gz!